# PCA works in R console but not in Jupyter IR kernel

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I am running this sample PCA code using `prcomp` in R console

```
C <- chol(S <- toeplitz(.9 ^ (0:31))) # Cov.matrix and its root
all.equal(S, crossprod(C))
set.seed(17)
X <- matrix(rnorm(32000), 1000, 32)
Z <- X %*% C  ## ==>  cov(Z) ~=  C'C = S
all.equal(cov(Z), S, tol = 0.08)
pZ <- prcomp(Z, tol = 0.1)
```

which works pretty fine. However, when I run the code in jupyter notebook with IRkernel (through jupyter hub to be specific), it keeps freezing and nothing happens.

I am on Ubuntu 18.04, here is my sessionInfo

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.199/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libmkl_rt.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8
 [4] LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.3
```

The only change I made was to link R to Intel MLK linear algebra library instead of base as you can see in sessionInfo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So something weird happened, I removed R4.0 and installed R3.6 and it worked.